# Running thousands of curl background processes in parallel in bash script

Tags: linux, performance, bash, curl, wget

I am running thounsand of **curl** background processes in parallel in the following bash script

```
START=$(date +%s)
for i in {1..100000}
do       
    curl -s "http://some_url_here/"$i  > $i.txt&
    END=$(date +%s)
    DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))
    echo "It took $DIFF seconds"
done
```

I have 49Gb Corei7-920 dedicated server (not virtual).

I track memory consumption and CPU through `top` command and they are far away from bounds.

I am using `ps aux | grep curl | wc -l` to count the number of current **curl** processes. 
This number increases rapidly up to 2-4 thousands and then starts to continuously decrease.

If I add simple parsing through piping curl to awk (`curl | awk > output`) than curl processes number raise up just to 1-2 thousands and then decreases to 20-30...

Why number of processes decrease so dramatically? Where are the bounds of this architecture?

Comment: You're probably hitting the one of the limits of max running processes or max open sockets. `ulimit` will show some of those limits.

Comment: I also would suggest using `parallel(1)` for such tasks: http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=parallel&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en

Comment: Try `start=$SECONDS` and `end=$SECONDS` - and use lower case or mixed case variable names by habit in order to avoid potential name collision with shell variables. However, you're really only getting the ever-increasing time interval of the starting of each process. You're not getting how long the download took since the process is in the background (and `start` is only calculated once). In Bash, you can do `(( diff = end - start ))` dropping the dollar signs and allowing the spacing to be more flexible. Use `pgrep` if you have it.

Comment: I agree with HBruijn. Notice how your process count is halved when you double the number of processes (by adding `awk`).

Comment: @zhenech @HBrujin I launched `parallel` and it says me that I may run just 500 parallel tasks due to system limit of file handles. I raised limit in limits.conf, but now when I try to run 5000 simulaneus jobs it instantly eats all my memory (49 Gb) even before start because every `parallel`  perl script eats 32Mb.

Comment: Original question didn't specify how long a single request takes... what if the earlier instances have completed?

Comment: Why don't you use [`ab`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ab) (apache benchmark)? You can set any concurrency.

Answer (score 16):

Following the question strict:

```
mycurl() {
    START=$(date +%s)
    curl -s "http://some_url_here/"$1  > $1.txt
    END=$(date +%s)
    DIFF=$(( $END - $START ))
    echo "It took $DIFF seconds"
}
export -f mycurl

seq 100000 | parallel -j0 mycurl
```

Shorter if you do not need the boilerplate text around the timings:

```
seq 100000 | parallel -j0 --joblog log curl -s http://some_url_here/{} ">" {}.txt
cut -f 4 log
```

If you want to run 1000s in parallel you will hit some limits (such as file handles). Raising ulimit -n or /etc/security/limits.conf may help.

Comment: And if I wish to run several commands as the one in the short answer version in parallel, how do I do that ?

Comment: Quote it: `seq 100 | parallel 'echo here is command 1: {}; echo here is command 2: {}'`. Spend an hour walking through the tutorial. Your command line will love you for it: `man parallel_tutorial`

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in {1..100000}
```

There are only 65536 ports. Throttle this.

```
for n in {1..100000..1000}; do   # start 100 fetch loops
        for i in `eval echo {$n..$((n+999))}`; do
                echo "club $i..."
                curl -s "http://some_url_here/"$i  > $i.txt
        done &
        wait
done
```

(edit: <strike>`echo`</strike>`curl`
(edit: strip severely dated assertion about OS limits and add the missing `wait`)

Comment: Actually the OS can handle this just fine. This is a limitation of TCP. No OS, no matter how special, will be able to get around it. But OP's 4k connections is nowhere near 64k (or the 32k default of some distros)

Comment: @Patrick okay, I took that part out, it's redundant with an irretrievable design limit, but look at [zavg's comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101632/running-thousands-of-curl-background-processes-in-parallel-in-bash-script/101677#comment154946_101632) on the 7th.

Answer (score 0):

try this shellscript for batch concurrent `curl` requesting:

*cat curlpool.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage: ./curlpool.sh "-d '{ \"id\": 1, \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\",  \"method\": \"cfx_getParamsFromVote\", \"params\": []}' -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:22537"

target=${1:-http://example.com}
cmd="curl $target"
concurrency=${2:-20}

while true # loop forever, until ctrl+c pressed.
do
    for i in $(seq $concurrency) # perfrom the inner command 100 times.
    do
        eval $cmd & # send out a curl request, the & indicates not to wait for the response.
        # or use `eval $cmd  > /dev/null &` if you don't want see the output.
    done

    wait # after all requests are sent out, wait for their processes to finish before the next iteration.
done
```