# Can GNU Parallel execute a bash script 25000 times per seconds and parallel processes?

Tags: command-line, curl, gnu-parallel

I am testing my web server response. Well I have a computer with 15 CPUs and 30 GB memory. How can I execute the following bash command on this computer 25000 times per second?

```
 curl -Z url="mywebserver.com" --data "{JSON DATA}"
```

I did the following which is worse and executes the shell 200 times per second.

```
 seq 25000 | parallel -j0 myshell
```

Comment: the `-Z` option is for parallel transfers, not parallel requests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running thousands of curl background processes in parallel in bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101632/running-thousands-of-curl-background-processes-in-parallel-in-bash-script)

Comment: @TimKennedy Actually mine is much simpler and would like very fundamental script for doing that with GNU parallel.

Comment: What is the important requirement here? Do you need _exactly_ 25000 times per second, no less and no more? Do you need _at least_ 25000 per second but are fine with more? Or maybe the opposite? You can't have more than 25000? Depending on your needs, the solution can be different. Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the comment. Indeed I need at least 25000per second  if this arise would be better and doing this for period of max 20 seconds.

Comment: This will likely bring your computer to its knees. You aren't using a particularly powerful computer, after all, It's only about equivalent to a couple of good laptops. I just tried on my laptop (8 CPUs, 32G RAM) and it killed it. There must be a better way to test your server than this.

Comment: @terdon What about a 24 Cpus and 50 GB Ram? Could you please let me know the bash script?

Comment: What I used was: `perl -e 'for(1..1000){ $p=fork(); if($p==0){ system("curl -Z url="mywebserver.com" --data "{JSON DATA}"")} } wait'`. But this is awful and broke my machine. It's basically a fork bomb and asking for trouble. Do _not_ do this.

Comment: @terdon You need to \-quote " inside ". On my system it tries to start 2^1000 processes. I think you meant: `perl -e 'for(1..1000){ if(not fork()) { exec("curl -Z url=\"mywebserver.com\" --data \"{JSON DATA}\"")} } wait'`

Comment: @OleTange oh, good grief, yes of course! I was testing using `command("sleep 10")` and just copy/pasted the OP's command in my comment above without really thinking about it. But either way, that's just a horrible thing to do to your machine!

Answer (score 1):

The CPU overhead of running a single GNU Parallel job is in the order of 1-10 ms. This is partly due to being written in Perl, but mostly due to a lot of safety tests happening behind the scenes.

So if you want to use GNU Parallel to run 25000 jobs per second on average, you can do:

```
seq 1000000 | parallel -n100 --pipe --round-robin -I ,, parallel myjob {}
```

You will need around 250 cores to do that.

(When you call `parallel` from `parallel` you get into the situation: Which `parallel` should replace the replacement strings? By using `-I dummy` or `-I ,,` in the outer `parallel` you can use `{}` in the inner `parallel` as you are used to.)

TL;DR: GNU Parallel is not made for very short jobs where run time is important.

`xargs` has very few safety tests, and that may be suitable here:

```
myjob() {
  curl -Z url="mywebserver.com" --data "{JSON DATA}"
}
export -f myjob
seq 25000 | parallel --pipe --block 100 --roundrobin xargs -n1 -P0 bash -c myjob >/dev/null
```

On my 48 core server this runs in 2.6s. So still not at the required 1s.

Comment: Could you explain what the specific options you're using are for? For example, why the `-I ,,`? I thought that changed the replacement string, so if you use `-I ,,` wouldn't you also need to say `parallel myjob ,,`?